unable to run deployment pipeline on bitbucket staging
When I am running a deployment pipeline its giving error.
bitbucker-pipeline.yml
image: atlassian/default-image:4

pipelines:
branches:
staging:
- step:
name: Build Docker Images
services:
- docker
caches:
- docker-cache  
script:
- docker build -t admintdocker08/admin_staging:python-${BITBUCKET_COMMIT:0:7} ./services/
- echo "$DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME" --password-stdin
- docker push admintdocker08/admin_staging:python-${BITBUCKET_COMMIT:0:7}

- step:
name: Deploy to Staging
deployment: staging
services:
- docker
 script:
  - pipe: atlassian/ssh-run:0.8.1
variables:
SSH_USER: "root"
SERVER: "$STAGING_SERVER_IP"
COMMAND: |
cd /root/deployment
PYTHON_TAG=${BITBUCKET_COMMIT:0:7} docker-compose -f deployment.yml up -d python

definitions:
  services:
    docker:
      memory: 2048
  caches:
    docker-cache: /var/lib/docker

Server deployment.yml file:
services:
python:
    image: admintdocker08/admin_staging:python-${PYTHON_TAG}
    container_name: python
    env_file: "python.env"
    ports:
      - "8010:8010"  # Map port 8010 inside the container to port 8010 on the host
    networks:
      - webnet
    restart: always

Error on the pipeline:
Status: Downloaded newer image for bitbucketpipelines/ssh-run:0.8.1
INFO: Executing the pipe...
INFO: Using default ssh key
INFO: Executing command on 191.1,2,3
ssh -A -tt -i /root/.ssh/pipelines_id -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p 22 root@191.1,2,3,4 bash -c cd /root/deployment
PYTHON_TAG=2art0b7 docker-compose -f deployment.yml up -d pythonai

@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:Dd5/fOmFyxv8KlHnz.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending ECDSA key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:8
Password authentication is disabled to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks.
Keyboard-interactive authentication is disabled to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks.
Agent forwarding is disabled to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks.
UpdateHostkeys is disabled because the host key is not trusted.
root@191.1.2.3.4: Permission denied (publickey,password).
✖ Execution failed.

I changed the bitbucker-pipeline.yml and deployment.yml file, but it doesn't work. Would like to get the automated pipeline running as soon as pipeline run. Currently its creating docker images on the docker hub but unable to deploy on the server.

You are using image atlassian/ssh-run you can see there

Prerequisites
If you want to use the default behaviour for using the configured SSH key and known hosts file, you must have configured the SSH private key and known_hosts to be used for this pipe in your Pipelines settings.

Going deeper you can find Update the known hosts and you can see how to add finger print to the known hosts

In Repository settings, go to SSH keys under the Pipelines header, and add the address for the known host. Click the Fetch button to see the host's fingerprint. Note: Bitbucket Pipelines automatically adds the fingerprint for the Bitbucket and GitHub sites to all pipelines (but doesn't display that in the UI shown above).

